# Where are added words of TortoiseSVN spell-checker saved?

Tags: tortoisesvn, spell-checking

In TortoiseSVN it is possible to add a word to the dictionary if the spell-checker does not know it. I did this a lot during the last 5 years. Now I have a new computer system and want to transfer the modifikations of the dictionary to my new computer system. But unfortunately I do not know where (in which file) TortoiseSVN stores these modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the %APPDATA%\TortoiseSVN folder there will be files ending in .dic. These are the dictionary files and you can view them in a text editor. In my case I have two 1033.dic for US or default English and 2057.dic for UK English.